# Rally Lookback API Only Retrieving Very Old Data

Tags: javascript, sdk, rally

Using a very broad search with Rally SDK 2.1:

```
Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore', {
            autoLoad: true,
            removeUnauthorizedSnapshots: true,
            filters: [
                {
                    property: '_TypeHierarchy',
                    operator: 'in',
                    value: ['HierarchicalRequirement']
                }
            ],
            listeners: {
                load: function(store, data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                scope:this
            }
        });
```

I'm only getting back around 2300 items from 2017. None of the projects mentioned in the unauthorized warnings are projects that I am associated with (and am looking to get snapshot data for) so I don't believe it is an authentication issue. All example searches [here](https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc/#/tryitnow) return no results. Any help to point me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tracked it down to a change in the project hierarchy which I have included in my query:

```
Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore', {
            autoLoad: true,
            removeUnauthorizedSnapshots: true,
            filters: [
                {
                    property: '_ProjectHierarchy',
                    value: 12345
                }
            ],
            listeners: {
                load: function(store, data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                scope:this
            }
        });
    }
```